# How to remove a move generator at run-time in OptaPlanner?

Tags: java, optaplanner

I have 4 different types of planning entities in my problem, and some problems have no entities of one or more types.
I have moves generators for all of them in the config file, and I would like to remove one or more such generators once I am given the problem. This is in order to avoid "bailing out of never-ending loops" and the associated slowdown (which I measured as a 42% increase in step time).

While the documentation states

> Every element in the solver configuration XML is available as a `*Config` class or a property on a `*Config` class in the package namespace `org.optaplanner.core.config`.

I was unable to even access the move generators - they seem to all be behind some `protected` method or field.

The question is: how can I remove some of the move generators at run-time, once I am given a problem file, given the path to the XML config file?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't configure any move selectors, you get the default ones (change and swap moves).
So the trick to remove those is to configure some in the solverConfig.xml:

```
<solver>
  ...
  <constructionHeuristics>
    <unionMoveSelector>
      ...
    </>
  </>
  <localSearch>
    <unionMoveSelector>
      ...
    </>
  </>
</>
```

See docs chapter on move selection.

Comment: Note that I doubt that this is a solution to your problem. First of all, upgrade to the latest optaplanner version (we fixed something that caused some bailout warnings).

Comment: I have a union move generator configured, and I want to remove some of its children based on whether all its entities are pinned. The documentation does not help in this. I also upgraded to 7.37 but my issues remain. Is it possible to remove the move generators programmatically?

Comment: I guess you could use the solver config API to remove them (see `SolverConfig.withSolverPhases(new LocalSearchPhaseConfig().with...)` etc), but that means you'd create a new SolverFactory for each dataset. Not ideal.

Comment: The other option is to use a move filter, but that that means the moves are still selected, just not scored.